# What does "theirs" refer to? "his auxiliaries"? Why don't use "them" nor "his" instead?

Tags: pronouns

Machiavelli "The Prince" Chapter XIII

Three of four English translations are the same.

W. Marriott (the last sentence, key points in Bold, hereinafter):

> And although ancient histories may be full of examples, I do not wish to leave this recent one of Pope Julius II, the peril of which cannot fall to be perceived; for he, wishing to get Ferrara, threw himself entirely into the hands of the foreigner. But his good fortune brought about a third event, so that he did not reap the fruit of his rash choice; because, having auxiliaries routed at Ravenna, and the Switzers having risen and driven out the conquerors (against all expectation, both his and others), it so came to pass that he did not become prisoner to his enemies, they having fled, nor to **his auxiliaries**, he having conquered by other arms than **theirs**.

N. Thomson:

> Ancient histories abound with instances of this, but I shall not pass from
>   the example of Pope Julius, which is still fresh in men’s minds. It was the height of rashness for him, in his eagerness to gain Ferrara, to throw himself without reserve into the arms of a stranger. Nevertheless, his good fortune came to his rescue, and he had not to reap the fruits of his ill-considered conduct. For after his auxiliaries were defeated at Ravenna, the Swiss suddenly descended and, to their own surprise and that of every one else, swept the victors out of the country, so that, he neither remained a prisoner with his enemies, they being put to flight, nor with **his auxiliaries**, because victory was won by other arms than **theirs**.

H. Mansfield:

> And although ancient histories are full of examples, nonetheless I do not wish to depart from this recent example of Pope Julius II, whose course of thrusting himself entirely into the hands of a foreigner, when he wanted Ferrara, could not have been less thought out. But his good fortune gave rise to a third thing so that he did not reap the fruit of his bad choice;f or when his auxiliaries were defeated at Ravenna, 1 the Swiss rose up and, beyond all expectation, his own and others, drove out the victors; and he came out a prisoner neither of his enemies, who had fled, nor of **his auxiliaries**, since he had won with other arms than **theirs**.

J. Bennett's translation is different:

> There are plenty of examples in ancient history, but I want to stay with Pope Julius II’s obviously dangerous decision to put himself at the mercy of a foreigner in his desire to get Ferrara. But his good fortuna brought a •third element ·into the equation·, saving him from the likely consequences of his rash choice: his ·Spanish· auxiliaries were defeated at Ravenna; •the Swiss, to his and everyone’s surprise, rose up and drove out the ·French· conquerors; so Julius didn’t become a prisoner of his enemies, because they fled, or to **his auxiliaries**, because **they** hadn’t given him his victory. ·But that was incredible good luck; it doesn’t make the Pope’s behaviour sensible·.

You see, it's "they" not "theirs".

Comment: "Theirs " refers to "arms"

Comment: @V.V. "auxiliaries' arms"? It sounds like "arms' arms", which is a little weird to me.

Comment: I would say that "theirs" means "the auxiliaries'".  He had won with other arms than *those belonging to the auxiliaries*.